# How to enable TLSv1.3 on Zookeeper 3.8

Tags: zookeeper

I had set the below properties in zoo.cfg to enable TLSv1.3 on zookeper 3.8.0 , but in the logs I see that zookeeper is connected to other zookeeper node on TLSv1.2 that is the default version. I want to know how can I enable TLSv1.3 on zookeeper 3.8.0

zookeeper.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.3 zookeeper.ssl.quorum.protocol=TLSv1.3

Tried to set the TLSv1.3 protocol in zoo.cfg file and was expecting ZK nodes communication on TLSv1.3